# Win32 assembly - is WNDCLASSEX.lpfnWndProc supposed to be _cdecl?

Tags: winapi, assembly

I've managed to write a simple Windows message loop in pure assembly. There's one thing that gave me a slight headache on the way there, and now I'm wondering why it is so.

This is my WndProc function (the one I specify in WNDCLASSEX.lpfnWndProc):

```
_WndProc:   ;LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

    PUSH EBP
    MOV EBP,ESP

    CMP DWORD [EBP+12d],WM_CLOSE    ;switch msg (UINT, second param)
    JNZ eval_wm_destroy
    PUSH DWORD [EBP+8d]
    CALL _DestroyWindow@4
    POP EBP
    RET

    eval_wm_destroy:
    CMP DWORD [EBP+12d],WM_DESTROY
    JNZ default_behavior
    PUSH 0
    CALL _PostQuitMessage@4
    POP EBP
    RET

    default_behavior:
    PUSH DWORD [EBP+20]
    PUSH DWORD [EBP+16]
    PUSH DWORD [EBP+12]
    PUSH DWORD [EBP+8]  
    CALL _DefWindowProcA@16

    POP EBP
    RET
;---
```

What I find slightly weird is that I'm not supposed to clean up the stack arguments in WndProc. The code posted above works, whereas if I try to do what I thought I should, like this:

```
CMP DWORD [EBP+12d],WM_CLOSE    ;switch msg (UINT, second param)
JNZ eval_wm_destroy
PUSH DWORD [EBP+8d]
CALL _DestroyWindow@4
POP EBP
ADD ESP,16d
RET
```

I get a crash. Such behavior suggests that the window procedure is *not* supposed to clean up after itself, making it... _cdecl?

Is that the case?

Comment: Everything in the Win32 API, except for `wsprintf()`, uses `__stdcall`, and has ever since Microsoft moved to 32-bit in Windows 95.  Back in the 16-bit days, everything was `__cdecl` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WndProc is supposed to use `WINAPI`, which is `stdcall` - that is, the function itself is supposed to clean up any arguments.

The reason it works anyway for you is probably that the calling scope doesn't rely on ESP being in the right place after the call and when it itself returns the stack is 'repaired' when ESP is reinitialized with the saved value from entry in EBP.

Comment: Okay, but then, me *trying* to clean up (ADD ESP,16d) should have no effect either, but as mentioned, it crashes the program.

Comment: It's probably your `POP EBP` causing that issue.

Comment: Well, the version that works (the first one) does have `POP EBP` in it.

Comment: In any case, the correct way to clean up after WndProc is to do `ret 16` in it.